# Append Column Pairs Below Each Other - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I received an excel list of orders. Each order is in a single line while the SKUs, Description and Quantities are merged each in a separate column.

| SKU | Description | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1, x2, x3 | Product1, Product2, Product3 | 1:10:6 |

I split the columns by the delimiters and I ended up with 23 columns each. I would like to get the column product and description pairs, below each other in a single table.

| SKU | Product |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | product1 |
| x2 | product2 |
| x3 | product3 |

I appreciate Your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom column that [splits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-split) and [zips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-zip) the [SKU] and [Description] columns into a list of lists, expand that list to new rows, and then create a new table from those rows.

Here's the full code for a sample query you can paste into your Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WqjDUUagwAmJjJR2lgKL8lNLkEqAQlGUEZ4GkDa0MDazMlGJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [SKU = _t, Description = _t, Quantity = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Zip({Text.Split([SKU], ", "), Text.Split([Description], ", ")})),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Table from Rows" = Table.FromRows(#"Expanded Custom"[Custom], {"SKU", "Product"})
in
    #"Table from Rows"
```